# Plugin to make selecting a page on a menu easier

Tags: 7, routes

I'm in the process of building a drupal site and wonder if there is an easier way to create menu items.

When I create a menu item in a menu I need to manually enter the url of the link for the item.  Is there a plugin available that will allow me to select from a list all the content created in the system so I can simply select the page I wish it to link to?

Obviously it would also need to allow me to type in a link for custom modules etc?

Does this exist as a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

[Content menu](https://drupal.org/project/content_menu) module improves Drupal's default menu management interface for tighter intergation of content authoring and menu management, so content can be created and edit right from the menu interface (e.g. creating content for a menu item that has been just created)

You can create a new menu item as

> - URL – With the traditional menu item form
> - Dummy – As a dummy menu item (with simple dummy link target)
> - New NODETYPE – directly create a new content for the new item
> - Existing content – selecting an existing content via a nice filterable view (if views is enabled)
> - Menu position rule (if the Menu Position module is enabled)